# How do I evaluate this sum :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n²}}{{(i\pi)}^{n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory

I'm interesting to know how do i evaluate this sum :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n²}}{{(i\pi)}^{n}}$$, I have tried to evaluate it using two partial sum for odd integer $n$ and even integer $n$ ,but i can't since it's alternating series ,and i would like to know if it's well know series also what about it's values :real or complex ? .

**Note** : [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%28%28-1%29%5En%2Fipi%29%5En%29,n%3D2+to+infty) showed that is a convergent series by the root test

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n²}}{{(i\pi)}^{n}} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n}}{{(i\pi)}^{n}} =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{1}}{{(-i\pi)}^{n}}$$

voilà geometric series!

Answer (score 2):

$(-1)^{n^2}=(-1)^n$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{i\pi}\right)^n$ is a geometric series. Since $\left|\frac{1}{i\pi}\right|=\frac{1}{\pi} < 1$, The series converges to $\frac{-\frac{1}{\pi i}}{1+\frac{1}{\pi i}}$.